# Does it imply to other side?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I've got this kind of statement in a book:

$(A \subset B) \Rightarrow ((A \setminus C) \subset (B \setminus C))$

Isn't it true for other side?

I assumed that $x \in A$. Then $x \in (A \setminus C) \Rightarrow x \in (B \setminus C)$. So $x \in B$ and $x \notin C$. And it has to be $A \subset B$. But someone gave me a contradiction by setting $A=\{1\}, B=\{2\}, C=\{1,2\}$. Could you also tell me where I may be wrong? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is true that $A\setminus C\subseteq B\setminus C$ implies that for all $x$ [$x\in A$ implies that [$x\in A\setminus C$ implies $x\in B\setminus C$]]. Materially, though, you said nothing about what happens if $x\in A$ and $x\notin A\setminus C$.